# Android 7.0 runnable on View not executing

Tags: android, webview, android-7.0-nougat

Edit - changed title to reflect real issue.

A very strange problem.
I have a layout that contains a WebView. It works perefectly apart from one phone that has recently updated to Android 7.0.
I'm fairly sure it isn't WebView that's a problem because other webviews in the same app continue to work fine.

I'm starting to think it's something to do with layouts within fragments being changed.

The mainactivity sets up the fragments like this..

```
private void initFragment() {
        orderFragment = new OrderFragment();
        settingFragment = new SettingFragment();
        driverListFragment = new DriverListFragment();
        driverDetailFragment = new DriverDetailFragment();

        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.main_container, orderFragment, OrderFragment.class.getName());
        ft.add(R.id.main_container, driverListFragment, DriverListFragment.class.getName());
        ft.add(R.id.main_container, settingFragment, SettingFragment.class.getName());

        String fromActivity = getIntent().getStringExtra(FROM_TO);
        if (LANGUAGE_SETTING_PAGE.equals(fromActivity)) {
            ft.hide(driverListFragment);
            ft.hide(orderFragment);
            ft.show(settingFragment);
            group.check(R.id.main_setting);
            mOption = 3;
        } else {
            mOption = 1;
            ft.hide(driverListFragment);
            ft.hide(settingFragment);
            ft.show(orderFragment);
            group.check(R.id.main_order);
        }
        ft.commit();


    }
```

when the menu item is pressed we do this...

```
case R.id.main_order:
            mOption = 1;
            flushOrderListData();
            ft.show(orderFragment);
            ft.hide(settingFragment);
            ft.hide(driverListFragment);
            break;
```

The flushOrderListData method...

```
private void flushOrderListData() {

        mWebViewProgress.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
        public void run() {

                mWebViewProgress.addJavascriptInterface(MainActivity.this, "android");
                mWebViewProgress.loadUrl(mUrl);
                orderFragment.layout.removeView(mWebViewProgress);
                orderFragment.layout.addView(mWebViewProgress);


        }
        });


    }
```

WebViewProgress is a class that extends WebView.

I'm 100% sure the issue is not there, the URL I want to display is ok from within a different layout.

Here's the XML..
I've tried removing everything except the webview but that made no difference.

Basically, absolutely nothing appears and there are no errors reported.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_top_order_all"
            style="@style/main_top_order_style"
            android:text="@string/main_top_order_all" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/bg_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_top_order_money"
            style="@style/main_top_order_style"
            android:text="@string/main_top_order_money" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/bg_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_top_order_card"
            style="@style/main_top_order_style"
            android:text="@string/main_top_order_card" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/bg_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_show_older"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.city.home.view.WebViewProgress
        android:id="@+id/web_order"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
public class WebViewProgress extends WebView {

    private ProgressBar progressbar;
    private View view_layout;

    public WebViewProgress(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public WebViewProgress(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void loadUrl(String url) {
        super.loadUrl(url);
        Log.i("Loading ",url);
    }

    private void init(final Context context) {

        Log.i("Webview","init");

        progressbar = new ProgressBar(context, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 4);

        progressbar.setLayoutParams(params);
        addView(progressbar);
        setJavaScript();
        setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {



            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error){
                Log.i("WebView","received SSL");
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setMessage("Problem with SSL Certificate");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        handler.proceed();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        handler.cancel();
                    }
                });
                final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();


            }


            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    Log.i("WebView", url + "");
                }
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }


            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    Log.i("WebViewPageFinished", url);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                Log.i("WebViewPageStarted", url);
            }
        });
        setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {

                Log.i("WebView","setWebChromeClient");

                if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    Log.d("Console",cm.message()+" "+cm.lineNumber());
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.i("WebView", url + "");
            }
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class WebChromeClient extends android.webkit.WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

            if (newProgress == 100) {
                if (view_layout != null) {
                    view_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                progressbar.setVisibility(GONE);
            } else {
                if (progressbar.getVisibility() == GONE){
                    progressbar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    }

                progressbar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
            if (Share.debug)
                Share.d("alert:" + message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 设置支持JavaScript
     */
    public void setJavaScript() {

        Log.i("WebView","setJavaScript");

        WebSettings ws = this.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        ws.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    }
```

OrderFragment

```
@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
public class OrderFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView main_top_order_all;
    private TextView main_top_order_money;
    private TextView main_top_order_card;
    public LinearLayout layout;
    public WebViewProgress mWeb;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_faq, null);
        layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        mWeb = (WebViewProgress) view.findViewById(R.id.web_order);
        main_top_order_all = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_top_order_all);
        main_top_order_money = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_top_order_money);
        main_top_order_card = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_top_order_card);

        loadData();
        return view;
    }

    /**
     * 加载数据
     */
    public void loadData() {

        String default_all = getResources().getString(R.string.main_top_order_all);
        String default_money = getResources().getString(R.string.main_top_order_money);
        String default_card = getResources().getString(R.string.main_top_order_card);
        int spColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.orange);
        main_top_order_all.setText(SpannalTextManager.getInstance().getTextHieght(default_all, "0/0.00", spColor));
        main_top_order_money.setText(SpannalTextManager.getInstance().getTextHieght(default_money, "0/0.00", spColor));
        main_top_order_card.setText(SpannalTextManager.getInstance().getTextHieght(default_card, "0/0.00", spColor));

    }

    public static OrderFragment newInstance() {
        OrderFragment fragment = new OrderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }



}
```

Comment: Where's the `WebView`?

Comment: It's WebViewProgress, it's a class that extends WebView

Comment: Ah. Please edit your question to specify that, as that class name makes it sound like a `ProgressBar`. You should also include the subclass in the post.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what the issue is but...
I read that if a view fails to attach to a window then code attached to a runnable on the view wont be executed. so, this...

```
 mWebViewProgress.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
        public void run() {

                mWebViewProgress.addJavascriptInterface(MainActivity.this, "android");
                mWebViewProgress.loadUrl(mUrl);
                orderFragment.layout.removeView(mWebViewProgress);
                orderFragment.layout.addView(mWebViewProgress);


        }
        });
```

was changed to this...

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

        //mWebViewProgress.post(new Runnable() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mWebViewProgress.loadUrl(mUrl);
                mWebViewProgress.addJavascriptInterface(MainActivity.this, "android");
                orderFragment.layout.removeView(mWebViewProgress);
                orderFragment.layout.addView(mWebViewProgress);
            }
        });
    }
```

et voila! it works fine.
I suppose some new code has subtlely changed the timings in view creation. (I'm only guessing here).

Comment: Using a new handler instead of view's post worked for me too.